# How to get user details from code parameter returned with redirect_url in stripe connect?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to get the details of a customer when he click on the "stripe connect" button,then after successful registration a `code` is returned with `redirect_url` as success message.

Can we use this code to get the customer details like name and email Id using php.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are saving the code in the same table along with each user's details in your Database

for e.g:

```
Name | Firstname   | Email    | Code
abc      abc        abc@a.com   123
```

So you can get all the fields related to the `code(123)`.Make sure your code will be unique in order to identify the user.